# Why is Pandas .isin() method faster than "=="

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering why

```
df['new_col'] = (df['old_col'] == 'string').astype(int)
815 µs ± 6.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

is slower than

```
df['new_col'] = df['old_col'].isin(['string']).astype(int)
334 µs ± 5.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: How large is your dataframe? Can you try with a much smaller or much larger one?

Comment: it is not so big, yet if i just concatenate replicas of it the difference is the same ~2.5 times slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is not representative. Use a larger dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 9, 100000))

%timeit df[0].isin([1])  # 12.8ms
%timeit df[0] == 1       # 285µs
```

For smaller dataframes, e.g. `nrows=10`, I see a warning for `isin` timeit: "The slowest run took 4.21 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached."

I wouldn't be concerned about microseconds. If you see significant performance differences for larger dataframes, then it might be worth investigating.

As a wise man once said, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

**Update**

There *does* appear to be some issue with `pandas` algorithms, which is not apparent in list comprehensions with numpy array equivalent:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_col':['string', 'new']})

df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True) 
arr = df.values

%timeit [i in ['string'] for i in arr]  # 106ms
%timeit [i == 'string' for i in arr]    # 106ms
%timeit df['old_col'].isin(['string'])  # 1.25ms
%timeit df['old_col'] == 'string'       # 2.88ms
```

The `isin` version uses [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), which is fairly efficient.

Comment: Hmmm, I think there should be says OP is right if many matches - `df = pd.DataFrame({'old_col':['string', 'new']})
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @jezrael, true. The best way to answer this is to dig into the source code. I've updated with more benchmarking.

Comment: Ya, agree, I guess some numba/C optimalization for `isin`, I have no idea.