# Why is pandas .isin much faster than "in"?

Tags: python, pandas

I am making an indicator column in my DataFrame to represent whether the value of a different column is in a list.

My first attempt used the base python "in" operator and my progress bar indicated it would take 83 hours to run. I then tried using the pandas ".isin()" and it took less than one second. My DataFrame has about 40,000,000 rows and the list I am searching in has about 100,000 items. The list has already been filtered to remove duplicate items (lst=list(set(original_list))). The items I am comparing are strings of about 20 characters.

Here is the my first attempt (that would have taken 83 hours):

```
df['indicator']=df['col1'].progress_apply(lambda x: 1 if x in lst else 0)
```

Here is my second attempt (that took less than one second):

```
df['indicator']=df['col1'].isin(tqdm(lst))
```

Can anyone explain why the second one leads to such a drastic improvement? The answer to [Why is Pandas .isin() method faster than "=="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275330/why-is-pandas-isin-method-faster-than) did not really explain it.

Comment: Your question should be `Why *isin* faster than *apply(lambda x: x in lst)*`, to which the answer is one is vectorized, the other is not.

Comment: Then `in` uses `Series.apply`, which is a loop, but with more overhead. The [`Series.isin`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.1/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L413-L480) uses some sophisticated reshaping a much faster methods.

Comment: Time-complexity-wise, since `.apply` is roughly a `for` loop, your first line of code has `O(N*M)` complexity, whereas your second line has `O(max(N, M))` (or `O(N+M)`) complexity, which is a great difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two methods is caused mostly by the performance of `x in X` operation. This test is of complexity `O(size_of_X)` when X is a list and `O(1)`if X is a set.

If you transform lst to `set` before `progress_apply`, you get mostly the same performance as `Series.isin`

Here is a quick benchmark

```
SERIES = pd.Series([str(i) for i in range(100000)])
LIST = [str(i) for i in range(-10000, 10000)]

%timeit SERIES.isin(LIST)
# 9.2 ms

SERIES.map(lambda x: x in LIST)
# 22000 ms

%timeit SET = set(LIST); SERIES.map(lambda x: x in SET)
# 24.8 ms
```

Comment: Thanks! lst in this example is actually list(set(my original list including duplicates)), so it wouldn't be that. Should have mentioned that in the post.

Comment: @jmh123 that doesn't matter. What makes a lookup faster in a set is not the fact that it has no duplicates, but rather the fact that it's got `O(1)` lookup due to hashing. Take a read on data structures (Google it!) for more info ;)